# How to get Inno Setup to unzip a file it installed (all as part of the one installation process)

Tags: zip, inno-setup, unzip

To save bandwidth/space as well as prevent accidental meddling, the installation files for a database product (call it Ajax), have been zipped up (call that file "AJAX_Install_Files.ZIP).  I would like to have Inno-Setup "install" (i.e., copy) the AJAX_Install_Files.ZIP file to the destination, and then Unzip the files into the same folder where the .ZIP file is located.  A subsequent program would be fired off by Inno Setup to actually run the install of product "Ajax".

I've looked through the documentation, FAQ, and KB at the [Inno Setup website](http://www.jrsoftware.org/), and this does not seem possible other than writing a Pascal script (code) - would that be correct, or are  there are any alternative solutions?

Comment: Don't. Innosetup itself compresses the files, and there's no benefit to double-compressing these files. It just slows down the install, requires more code, more disk space during installation, and adds failure modes to the process.

Answer (score 27):

You can use an external command line tool for unzipping your archive, see [here](http://stahlworks.com/dev/index.php?tool=zipunzip) for example. Put it in your [Files] section:

```
[Files]
Source: "UNZIP.EXE"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: deleteafterinstall
```

Then call it in your [Run] section, like this:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{tmp}\UNZIP.EXE"; Parameters: "{tmp}\ZipFile.ZIP -d C:\TargetDir"
```

(You'll probably want to take your target directory from a script variable, so there is some more work that needs to be done)

Comment: Is there any way to hide logs showed in the screen?

Comment: @TalyssondeCastro Use `Flags: runhidden`.

Comment: Correct, BUT I needed to add quotes around the .zip and target dir.  To do this, you have to escape with annother set of quotes so it looked like:
"""{tmp}\ZipFile.ZIP"" -d ""C:\TargetDir"""

Comment: Keep in mind, you should add the `-o` flag when unzipping. Otherwise this process will hang indefinitely if a file needs to be overwritten.

Answer (score 15):

You can use the shell [`Folder.CopyHere` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folder-copyhere) to extract a ZIP.

```pascal
const
  SHCONTCH_NOPROGRESSBOX = 4;
  SHCONTCH_RESPONDYESTOALL = 16;

procedure UnZip(ZipPath, TargetPath: string); 
var
  Shell: Variant;
  ZipFile: Variant;
  TargetFolder: Variant;
begin
  Shell := CreateOleObject('Shell.Application');

  ZipFile := Shell.NameSpace(ZipPath);
  if VarIsClear(ZipFile) then
    RaiseException(
      Format('ZIP file "%s" does not exist or cannot be opened', [ZipPath]));

  TargetFolder := Shell.NameSpace(TargetPath);
  if VarIsClear(TargetFolder) then
    RaiseException(Format('Target path "%s" does not exist', [TargetPath]));

  TargetFolder.CopyHere(
    ZipFile.Items, SHCONTCH_NOPROGRESSBOX or SHCONTCH_RESPONDYESTOALL);
end;
```

Note that the flags `SHCONTCH_NOPROGRESSBOX` and `SHCONTCH_RESPONDYESTOALL` work on Windows Vista and newer.

---

You can use the function for example like this:

```
[Files]
Source: "archive.zip"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; AfterInstall: UnZipCurrentFileTo('{app}')
```

Place this auxiliary function below `UnZip`:

```pascal
procedure UnZipCurrentFileTo(TargetPath: string);
begin
  UnZip(ExpandConstant(CurrentFileName), ExpandConstant(TargetPath));
end;
```

Though if you would use it just once, you can instead do:

```
[Files]
Source: "archive.zip"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; \
 AfterInstall: UnZip(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\archive.zip'), ExpandConstant('{app}'))
```

---

For an example of extracting some files only, see:
[How to get Inno Setup to unzip a single file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44378509/850848)

Comment: Slick, but locks up the UI if the zip file is large.  Though, the script could be packaged as a .ps1 file and launched in the same manner as this example launches 7zip: https://gist.github.com/jakoch/33ac13800c17eddb2dd4

Answer (score 8):

I answered a very [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997666/unpack-data-files-before-starting-inno-setup/6002438#6002438) and some of the details apply.

I would question why you need a ZIP file of the contents?   I personally would place the uncompressed files into the setup.   I would then have two `[category]` entries one for the application and one for the data.  Default both the be checked.

This would allow the users to install a fresh set of the data if needed at a later date.

If you really want a ZIP file and want to keep it easy you could, ship both the zip files and the uncompressed files in the same setup.

*Update:*

By default files that get placed in your setup.exe are [compressed](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_compression).

You can also have the files extracted to a temporary location so you can run your
installation application, then have them deleted.

```
[Files]
Source: "Install1.SQL"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags:deleteafterinstall;
Source: "Install2.SQL"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags:deleteafterinstall;
```

Comment: Why a zip of the contents - because that is how the files are supplied to me, & I think it is *much* easier to deal with a single .ZIP file rather than the 2,000 plus files saved in the .ZIP file.  This .ZIP file is the installation and data for just one program of a multiple program installation that I am attempting to automate.  Once I get the files "installed" (actually copied) to the target machine, I then am going to launch the database installation program and use another automation tool to install it automatically.  So ultimately, I need to repeat the above process many (>2) times.

Comment: if i don't deploy the zip file?

Answer (score 1):

You can just create silent self-extracting archive (SFX) archive, example described here [how to create SFX archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17698055/how-to-create-self-extracting-rar-archive-not-showing-anything-on-execution) for stuff you need, and write Pascal code to just run it like this (script for Inno Setup 6.0.2):

```
[Tasks]
Name: "intallSenselockDriver"; Description: "Install Senselock driver."; GroupDescription: "Install the necessary software:";

[Code]
function ExecTmpFile(FileName: String): Boolean;
var
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  if not Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\' + FileName), '', '', SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)
  then
    begin
      MsgBox('Other installer failed to run!' + #13#10 + SysErrorMessage(ResultCode), mbError, MB_OK);
      Result := False;
    end
  else
    Result := True;
end;

procedure RunOtherInstallerSFX(ArchiveName: String; ExePath: String);
begin
  ExtractTemporaryFile(ArchiveName);
  ExecTmpFile(ArchiveName);
  ExecTmpFile(ExePath);
end;

function PrepareToInstall(var NeedsRestart: Boolean): String;
begin
  if WizardIsTaskSelected('intallSenselockDriver') then
    RunOtherInstallerSFX('1_senselock_windows_3.1.0.0.exe', '1_senselock_windows_3.1.0.0\InstWiz3.exe');

  Result := '';
end;
```

It worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score -1):

Using Double quotes worked for me.
Single quotes were not working.

```
[Files]
Source: "unzip.exe"; DestDir: "{userappdata}\{#MyAppName}\{#InputFolderName}"; Flags: ignoreversion 

[Run]
Filename: "{userappdata}\{#MyAppName}\{#InputFolderName}\unzip.exe"; Parameters: " ""{userappdata}\{#MyAppName}\{#InputFolderName}\ZIPFILENAME.zip""  -d  ""{userappdata}\{#MyAppName}\{#InputFolderName}""  ";  Flags: runascurrentuser
```