# Setup using inno

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I have finished my .NET application but I could not figure out how to handle finishing it's setup as it seems a bit complicated to me.

So I was thinking of using InnoSetup, but unfortunately I don't know anything about it.

In brief I want to make a setup for doing these tasks:

1. Install .NET Framework 4.0, if not available
2. Install Crystal report runtime engine 13 according to your system 32-bit or 64-bit
3. Install MSSQL Server Express 2008 (32-bit or 64-bit depending on user's OS) with these settings

   - SQL Server instance name: SQLEXPRESS
   - Authentication mode: Mixed
   - Username: user1
   - Password: pass1
4. Ask about language selection (Arabic or English) for installing my app (MyApp.exe) and install accordingly the selected version.
5. Of course before installing my app there should be one windows about License Agreement

I think this is not very difficult except for SQL server part,

Please guys if anyone can help me and give me Inno code for doing this setup.
Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but from 8 months on StackOverflow, you might observe that this is not a *give me the code* site. If you search, I bet you'll find more than a half of your requirements already scripted here, so try to do so and don't hesitate to come up with a specific question. Voting to close...

Comment: I was afraid that someone like you would say something like this to me,although you are right but It happens sometimes that you need this piece of code right now especially when you are a surgeon and too preoccupied by many tasks that fill all your daily hours and you do not have time to even scratch your head and in the same time you have this hobby that is keeping you alive and you can not leave it behind ,So what to do ? please do not vote for close instead vote for helping me.Thanks

Comment: What to do ? Minimize your problem, search for already made scripts (I know at least that I've posted something about 1., 3., 4. I can answer you if you ask it as a separate post, if it's not already answered here), 5. that's what I'm not sure, what you mean. In all cases, don't take it personally, but what you're requesting is much work and won't help to anyone else (and that should be the main point of this site).

Comment: #5 is pretty straightforward too if you read the Inno help file.

Comment: Divide and conquer, that's a way to learn things as @TLama suggested, and that's how you can find answers/valuable ideas on SO. When you simply posted a checklist and expect someone to do all for you, you hurt your own reputation and nobody is willing to help.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that hard to learn the Inno Setup scripting language, so you should definitely read the [documentation](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/).

For installing .NET dependencies, check out [THIS](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20868/NET-Framework-1-1-2-0-3-5-Installer-for-InnoSetup) CodeProject article. I used a slightly different approach. I added my dependencies as zip archives, thus I didn't need to list my files, and also added [unzip.exe](http://stahlworks.com/dev/index.php?tool=zipunzip) and used it to extract them to the temporary folder and launch the installer from there. [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065364/how-to-get-inno-setup-to-unzip-a-file-it-installed-all-as-part-of-the-one-inst)'s an SO question explaining how to do it.

Some of the stuff you asked for are supported features of InnoSetup. E.g. use the [[Languages]](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=languagessection) section for selecting language or the [LicenseFile](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_licensefile) parameter for license agreement.