# How to create self-extracting RAR archive not showing anything on execution?

Tags: winrar, sfx

I am trying to create a self-extracting archive that extracts to "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop" with WinRar. However, when I run it, it extracts to the SFX's current directory, not my desktop. Does the *path to extract* option work at all?

I'm using the 32-bit command line module.

I also checked the 'hide all' box for silent mode which appears to do absolutely nothing and the command prompt window still appears with showing information on what is extracted.

I want that SFX archive extracts the .exe and the folder contained in the SFX file to the desktop without any messages popping up.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 12):

It is possible to create an SFX RAR archive extracting all files and folders directly to
`"%USERPROFILE%\Desktop"` without showing a window.

This can be done with **WinRAR** after selecting the files and folders and clicking on icon **Add** in the toolbar by

1. checking on tab **General** the option *Create SFX archive*,
2. clicking on tab **Advanced** on button **SFX options**,
3. entering on SFX tab **General** for *Path to extract* the string `"%USERPROFILE%\Desktop"` which results in automatic selection of option *Absolute path* which is right,
4. selecting on SFX tab **Modes** the option *Hide all*,
5. selecting on SFX tab **Module** the SFX module *Default.sfx* (WinRAR GUI SFX module),
6. closing *Advanced SFX options* window with button **OK**,
7. entering on tab **General** the name for the SFX archive,
8. and starting compression with button **OK**.

A command prompt window will be always displayed if module *WinCon.sfx* is used for the SFX archive as in this case Windows detects automatically on start of the SFX archive that this is a console application and opens a command prompt window in which the console SFX is executed.

Creating such an SFX archive can be done also with a batch file:

```
@echo off
echo ;The comment below contains SFX script commands>"%TEMP%\SfxOptions.txt"
echo/>>"%TEMP%\SfxOptions.txt"
echo Path="%%USERPROFILE%%\Desktop">>"%TEMP%\SfxOptions.txt"
echo Silent=^1>>"%TEMP%\SfxOptions.txt"
"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -c -cfg- -ep1 -idq -m5 -mdg -r -s -sfx -y "-z%TEMP%\SfxOptions.txt" "Path\Name of your SFX.exe" "Path\Folder to add" "Path\File to add"
if errorlevel 1 goto Failure
del "%TEMP%\SfxOptions.txt"
goto :EOF

:Failure
del "%TEMP%\SfxOptions.txt"
echo/
echo Error on creation of "Path\Name of your SFX.exe"
echo/
pause
```

In this batch file must be modified for usage:

1. Path to program files folder of **WinRAR** containing console version `Rar.exe` and also the SFX module *Default.sfx*.
2. Path and name of the SFX archive to create.
3. Path and name of folder and/or file to add to the archive.

The used switches are explained in text file **Rar.txt** in program files folder of **WinRAR**.

One more note on switch `-ep1`:

Everything up to last backslash in name of folder and/or file to add to archive is removed from name on adding the folder or file to the archive.

On adding a folder to a RAR archive it makes a difference if the folder is specified with or without a backslash at end.

Example:

A directory tree like

- C:\Temp

  - MyFolder

    - Subfolder 1
    - Subfolder 2

      - File X
    - File Y

is compressed with

```
Rar.exe a -ep1 -r C:\Temp\Demo1.rar C:\Temp\MyFolder
```

with following files and folders in archive `C:\Temp\Demo1.rar`

- MyFolder

  - Subfolder 1
  - Subfolder 2

    - File X
  - File Y

while using

```
Rar.exe a -ep1 -r C:\Temp\Demo2.rar C:\Temp\MyFolder\
```

or using

```
Rar.exe a -ep1 -r C:\Temp\Demo2.rar C:\Temp\MyFolder\*
```

results in following files and folders in archive `C:\Temp\Demo2.rar`

- Subfolder 1
- Subfolder 2

  - File X
- File Y