# Create WinRAR SFX with admin rights by command line

Tags: batch-file, console, winrar, sfx

I need to create WinRAR SFX archive that should work with admin permissions on Windows 7. I can make it with WinRAR GUI but I need to make it with WinRAR command line interface (to integrate it into build process).
At the moment my script is like that:

```
rar.exe a -sfxdefault.sfx archive.exe some_file_to_be_in_sfx
rar.exe c archive.exe -zscenario.txt
```

while scenario.txt is

```
TempMode="Extract data from archive?","Title"
```

Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, take a look on question [How can I automate the building of this Winrar Sfx File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28194942/how-can-i-automate-the-building-of-this-winrar-sfx-file).

Second, if you have open the tab **Advanced** of **Advanced SFX options** dialog with the option *Request administrative access* in *WinRAR* GUI, there is a button **Help** which opens the help page for this dialog. This help page contains:

> **Request administrative access**
>   Set this option if you wish to create SFX archive, which will request the administrative access when started in Windows Vista and later. This option does not change behavior of SFX archive in older Windows versions.
>
> Corresponding command line switch is -iadm.

And this answers your question. `-idam` is on help page a hyperlink to the help page of this switch.

But the text file `Rar.txt` in program files folder of *WinRAR* containing an explanation of all commands and switches supported by console version `Rar.exe` does not list this switch nor does `Rar.exe` output it on running it from within a command prompt window with no parameters to get displayed the help for console version.

This means only `WinRAR.exe` supports the switch `-iadm`, but not console version `Rar.exe`. But this is no problem as `WinRAR.exe` can be executed also from within a batch file from console, best with using background process option `-ibck`.

Note: Best on creating the command line for `WinRAR.exe` is opening in help the page **Alphabetic switches list** via **Contents - Command line mode - Switches** and read from top to bottom while building the command line. Add the switches you need for creating the SFX archive.

For example:

```
WinRAR.exe a -cfg- -ep1 -iadm -ibck -inul -k -m5 -ma4 -md4m -r -s -sfxdefault.sfx -tl -y -zscenario.txt archive.exe some_file_to_be_in_sfx
```

Comment: I thought by mistake that rar.exe is just a console version of WinRAR.exe :)

Answer (score 0):

May be Its too late to answer this Question but Simple solution to this is command

```
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a helpTestUpdate -s -sfx  logFile.txt
```

This will take the logFile.txt and convert it to the .exe sfx file.