# download .zip files with IDP: Download plugin for Inno Setup, and unpack them

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript, inno-download-plugin

sorry for my english.

Hi
 my installer will download files , by the addition of " IDP : Download plugin for Inno Setup," and I have a problem because they are downloaded in .zip format so need to be extracted , whether it is possible to be unpacked where the application ? It is an add-on or something?
Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065364/how-to-get-inno-setup-to-unzip-a-file-it-installed-all-as-part-of-the-one-inst

Comment: Yes, but this is not the effect that I want , and of that person did not benefit from the said allowance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can ship the unzip tool of your choice and use it for extraction.

I tend to ship "7za" (the command-line version of 7zip), because i found out that it's extraction speed is really good (and better than unzip).

**Firstly, you integrate the extraction tool into your installer.**

```
    [Files]
    Source: ..\utils\unzip\7za.exe; DestDir: {tmp}; Flags: dontcopy
    Source: and some zip files ...
```

Note the `dontcopy`. This will not copy the file to the user system during the normal file copying stage, but statically compile the file into the installation.

**Secondly, you might add a little `DoUnzip` helper method to your `[Code]` section.**

It will use the tool from the temp folder.

```
procedure DoUnzip(source: String; targetdir: String);
var 
    unzipTool: String;
    ReturnCode: Integer;
begin
    // source contains tmp constant, so resolve it to path name
    source := ExpandConstant(source);

    unzipTool := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\7za.exe');

    if not FileExists(unzipTool)
    then MsgBox('UnzipTool not found: ' + unzipTool, mbError, MB_OK)
    else if not FileExists(source)
    then MsgBox('File was not found while trying to unzip: ' + source, mbError, MB_OK)
    else begin
         if Exec(unzipTool, ' x "' + source + '" -o"' + targetdir + '" -y',
                 '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ReturnCode) = false
         then begin
             MsgBox('Unzip failed:' + source, mbError, MB_OK)
         end;
    end;
end;
```

**Thirdly, you extract the unzip tool, then the zips and then you simply use the DoUnzip() method on the zips.** These commands are for the `[Code]` section.

```
  // extract 7za to temp folder
  ExtractTemporaryFile('7za.exe');

  // extract the zip to the temp folder (when included in the installer)
  // skip this, when the file is downloaded with IDP to the temp folder
  //ExtractTempraryFile('app.zip);

  targetPath := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\');

  // unzip the zip in the tempfolder to your application target path
  DoUnzip(targetPath + 'app.zip', ExpandConstant('{app}'));
```

Comment: I would go either this way, or import e.g. 7-Zip DLL functions (if it's possible). There is yet one more option that I *stole* from [`this lazy`](http://www.scriptkitties.com/innounzip/) plugin which uses Windows Shell for this task. With that it's enough to write [`something like this`](http://pastebin.com/qWxvTFDx) when using late binding. However, I'm not sure when was added built-in support for archives in Shell (not speaking about quite poor performance).

Comment: Using the CopyHere functionality of Shell.Application for unzipping is a nice trick. It saves you from shipping an additional tool. Also a pretty compact little wrapper function - i like it. Because of "noprogressbox", i wonder if it's possible to grab the extraction progress from CopyHere and display it. // The downside of my approach is, that it locks the Innosetup window up during the time of the extraction and i still haven't found a way around that.

Comment: Not for this script object method. I believe there will be some way with early binding (since Vista something around `IFileOperation` interface, I think). A flat function (if there is one) would almost surely require a callback with the `stdcall` calling convention, which would in turn require external plugin (InnoCallback.dll), so no big deal again.

Comment: @TLama I'm trying to use your code from pastebin, but I get an error on the CopyHere line that reads "NIL interface exception." Do you know why this could be?