# Is there a way to extract .zip files in Inno Setup after a certain page is done?

Tags: inno-setup

So I basically have a .zip file in my `{tmp}` directory, and want to extract it's contents in `{tmp}` but only when my third form is done with it's work, not earlier. The reason is: Because in the third form I download this .zip from the internet and it is saved into `{tmp}`. Now after this I want to extract these files into `{tmp}` from which I am to get the files from the extracted folders, like the release notes, license agreement files to use in the rest of the forms in the installer. Meaning, already in the form after the third one, I am using the files extracted.

I can't find anywhere how to do this after a certain form. I only found in the run section how extracting is done.

Comment: Please, show what you have. Edit your post and add the relevant part of your Inno Setup script, and let us know what plugins you use.

Comment: I will have to do that on monday, because i do not have that PC with me before that. I don't have any plugins for extracting, just downloading over the internet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDIT:** The old way I described proved not to work well on some Windows versions. It may pop up a dialog window instead of overwriting files silently. This is easy to google: *[CopyHere ignores options](https://www.google.com/search?q=CopyHere%20ignores%20options)*.

**The new way:**

- [Mitchich Inno Download plugin](https://bitbucket.org/mitrich_k/inno-download-plugin)
- [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html)

The new way uses [7zip standalone console version](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html). It is a single `7za.exe`, you don't need the DLLs.

```pascal
#include <idp.iss>

; Languages section
; Includes for Mitrich plugin's additional languages
; #include <idplang\Russian.iss>

[Files]
Source: "7za.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: deleteafterinstall;

[Run]
Filename: {tmp}\7za.exe; Parameters: "x ""{tmp}\example.zip"" -o""{app}\"" * -r -aoa"; Flags: runhidden runascurrentuser;

[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  idpAddFile('https://example.comt/example.zip', ExpandConstant('{tmp}\example.zip'));
  { Download after "Ready" wizard page }
  idpDownloadAfter(wpReady);
end;
```

If you want to download, **unzip and use files (for example, as license agreement) before the installation starts**, I can only give the general guideline:

1. Enable welcome page in `[Setup]`: `DisableWelcomePage=no`.
2. Use `idpDownloadAfter(wpWelcome);`. Now it downloads right after "Welcome" page.
3. You need an empty license file in `[Setup]`: `LicenseFile=license.txt` for license page to show up. Or probably not empty, but with "Loading license agreement..." text.
4. You implement `procedure CurPageChanged()`: if current page is `wpLicense` then you call `Exec()` function to launch 7zip and wait for it to terminate. No 7zip in `[Run]` section now. Then you probably use `LoadStringFromFile()` function to get license agreement from extracted file. Then put it into UI. Probably `WizardForm.LicenseMemo.RTFText = ...` should work. Anyway, UI is accessible, if you have trouble setting the text, ask a separate question on this.

**The *old buggy way*:**

- [Mitchich Inno Download plugin](https://bitbucket.org/mitrich_k/inno-download-plugin)
- [Inno Unzip Plugin](http://www.scriptkitties.com/innounzip/)

An equivalent, cleaner way without `unzipper.dll` is [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065364/how-to-get-inno-setup-to-unzip-a-file-it-installed-all-as-part-of-the-one-inst/40706549#40706549). One way or another, it uses buggy [CopyHere](https://www.google.com/search?q=CopyHere%20ignores%20options) Windows feature.

```pascal
#include <idp.iss>

; Languages section
; Includes for Mitrich plugin's additional languages
; #include <idplang\Russian.iss>

[Files]
Source: "unzipper.dll"; Flags: dontcopy

[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  idpAddFile('https://example.comt/example.zip', ExpandConstant('{tmp}\example.zip'));
  { Download after "Ready" wizard page }
  idpDownloadAfter(wpReady);
end;

procedure unzip(src, target: AnsiString);
external 'unzip@files:unzipper.dll stdcall delayload';

procedure ExtractMe(src, target : AnsiString);
begin
  unzip(ExpandConstant(src), ExpandConstant(target));
end;

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then 
  begin
    { Extract when "Finishing installation" setup step is being performed. }
    { Extraction crashes if the output dir does not exist. }
    { If so, create it first: }
    { CreateDir(ExpandConstant(...)); }
    ExtractMe('{tmp}\example.zip', '{app}\');
  end;
end;
```

You can probably try other things instead of `wpReady` and `ssPostInstall`. For my small zip this works well.

Comment: Note that using the `unzipper.dll` is an overkill. You can implement the same using a native Pascal Script code. See [How to get Inno Setup to unzip a file it installed (all as part of the one installation process)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40706549/850848).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl That's good, thank you. I'll check it out and edit my answer if it works well.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I found out `CopyHere` may ignore the options on some Windows versions. I updated my answer, now I simply use 7zip.

Comment: The flags work on Windows Vista and newer. I've added this to my answer.

Comment: In this new way, how do you know that it is unzipped after it is downloaded?

Comment: @HeraldJones The download is performed immediately after the `wpReady` page. Unzipping is in the `[Run]` section, which is executed as a part of installation, I believe, it's `wpInstalling` page. Anyway, I've tested it and it works as is.

Comment: I need the unzipping to take place before the installing, before the license agreement. This is because i get the license agreement from the extracted zip... How do I do this?

Comment: @HeraldJones I've updated the answer, right below the new solution. I do not have exact code for your tricky scenario, but I have some general steps.

Comment: Make sure you add double quotes around the `{tmp}` and `{app}` in `7za.exe` parameters.