# Display license extracted from downloaded ZIP file in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

How do use files that are downloaded in the `[Code]` section then unzipped in the `[Run]` section, as files to be installed?

Here is my code. The thing is, I want the zip files extracted after my downloads are finished. I don't think I have that here in my code. Because when I type this I get an error:

Under

```
[Setup]
LicenseFile={tmp}\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13\LICENSE
InfoBeforeFile={tmp}\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13\NOTICE
InfoAfterFile={tmp}\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13\RELEASE-NOTES
```

Under

```
[Files]
Source: "{tmp}\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13\bin\tomcat9.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\...\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
```

I get compilation errors like that the file doesn't exist.

How do I use the files I downloaded and extracted as license and release notes?

I am not sure that the the .zip file is even extracted at the stage I wanted to be extracted. Here is my code that compiles based on these questions:

- [Is there a way to extract .zip files in Inno Setup after a certain page is done?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40704442/850848)
- [Running a program after it is downloaded in Code section in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40679399/850848)

```pascal
#include <idp.iss>

[Setup]
LicenseFile=C:\..\Desktop\x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13\LICENSE
InfoBeforeFile=C:\...\x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13\NOTICE
InfoAfterFile=C:\...\x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13\RELEASE-NOTES
DisableWelcomePage=no

[Files]
Source: "C:\...\x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "7za.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: deleteafterinstall;

[Code]

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  idpAddFile('http://www-us.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.0.M13/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13-windows-x64.zip', ExpandConstant('{tmp}\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13-windows-x64.zip'));
  idpDownloadAfter(wpWelcome);
end;

[Run]
Filename: {tmp}\7za.exe; Parameters: "x {tmp}\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13-windows-x64.zip -o{app}\ * -r -aoa"; Flags: runhidden runascurrentuser;
```

Comment: Do you want to "install" (=copy) the downloaded ZIP to the {app}? Why? Anyway, why don't you download it directly to `{app}`, instead of `{tmp}`?

Comment: I will accept that answer later today.

Comment: And you still need to explain this question.

Comment: I will correct my other posts accordingly this afternoon. I do want to install the downloaded zip. I have trouble doing this. Also i cannot format the question so it looks presentable because i am on my phone. This afternoon i will tie us all loose ends on my posts.

Comment: The problem that i have here also is that the unzipping seems to happen during the installing wizard page, because it is in the run section. I need it to unzip right after the downloads are finished, before the license agreement, because i am to get the license agreement from the downloaded zip.

Comment: But you know how to trigger an action just after the download finishes. You execute the installer this way already according [to this answer that you never accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40679399/850848). All you need to do is to call the `ExtractMe` function from [this answer that you never accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40705360/850848) the same way (The answer is actually good, despite the poster labeling it "buggy". It just pops up progress window on Windows XP, but that's a minor issue).

Comment: If you cannot format a question on phone, do not post questions from phone. That's a lame excuse!

Comment: The reasons why i cannot post from my computer in the mornings are very complicated. I thank you for your input very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Enable the "license" page, by setting a fake license file.
- Download the ZIP file with the license just after a welcome page (you have to explicitly enable it).
- In the "next" button handler of the download page, extract the ZIP file, and load the license (you have to code this, you cannot use the `[Run]` section).

The code uses an `UnZip` function from [How to get Inno Setup to unzip a file it installed (all as part of the one installation process)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6065364/850848#40706549) that uses the `Shell.Application`. If you prefer an external unzip application, you can execute it using `Exec` function, on the same place the `UnZip` is called.

```pascal
#include "idp.iss"

[Setup]
DisableWelcomePage=no
LicenseFile=fake.txt

const
  TomcatVersion = '9.0.0.M13';

var
  TomcatZipPath: string;

procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  TomcatZipUrl: string;
  TomcatZipFile: string;
begin
  TomcatZipFile := 'apache-tomcat-' + TomcatVersion + '-windows-x64.zip';
  TomcatZipPath := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\' + TomcatZipFile);
  TomcatZipUrl :=
    'http://www-us.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-9/v' + TomcatVersion +
    '/bin/' + TomcatZipFile;
  idpAddFile(TomcatZipUrl, TomcatZipPath);
  idpDownloadAfter(wpWelcome);
end;

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  if CurPageID = IDPForm.Page.ID then
  begin
    idpShowDetails(False);
    IDPForm.DetailsButton.Visible := False;

    WizardForm.NextButton.Enabled := False;
    WizardForm.BackButton.Visible := False;
    WizardForm.CancelButton.Enabled := False;
    try
      IDPForm.TotalProgressLabel.Caption := 'Extracting files...';
      UnZip(TomcatZipPath, ExpandConstant('{tmp}'));
    finally
      WizardForm.BackButton.Visible := True;
      WizardForm.NextButton.Enabled := True;
      WizardForm.CancelButton.Enabled := True;
    end;

    WizardForm.LicenseMemo.Lines.LoadFromFile(
      ExpandConstant('{tmp}\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13\LICENSE'));
  end;

  Result := True;
end;
```

[image: Downloading]

[image: Extracting]

[image: License]

Comment: I agree, but how do i integrate this with that java installation, which is also inside next button event

Comment: I need that java installation to go through then get this screen. I tried puttting thwm together, it compiled but when pressing the first next button i got an error

Comment: That's a new question. Ask it. And show us your new code.

Comment: Though, you just probably want to change the `if CurPageID = DownloadPage.ID then` from http://stackoverflow.com/a/40683075/850848 to `if CurPageID = wpLicense then`, don't you?

Comment: Tried that, got problems. Ill try this out later. Thabk you so much for your help with inno setup. I am comming to an end soon.