# How to get Inno Setup to unzip a single file?

Tags: winapi, zip, inno-setup, pascalscript

Is there a way to unzip just one file from a zip?
I'm using code based on [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40706549/7655446) for  [How to get Inno Setup to unzip a file it installed (all as part of the one installation process)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065364/how-to-get-inno-setup-to-unzip-a-file-it-installed-all-as-part-of-the-one-inst), works perfect for unzip but don't have an idea how can it unzip a single file:

```pascal
[Code]:

const
  NO_PROGRESS_BOX = 4;
  RESPOND_YES_TO_ALL = 16;

procedure UnZip(ZipPath, TargetPath: string); 
var
  Shell: Variant;
  ZipFile: Variant;
  TargetFolder: Variant;
begin
  Shell := CreateOleObject('Shell.Application');

  ZipFile := Shell.NameSpace(ZipPath);
  if VarIsClear(ZipFile) then
    RaiseException(Format('ZIP file "%s" does not exist or cannot be opened', [ZipPath]));

  TargetFolder := Shell.NameSpace(TargetPath);
  if VarIsClear(TargetFolder) then
    RaiseException(Format('Target path "%s" does not exist', [TargetPath]));

  TargetFolder.CopyHere(ZipFile.Items, NO_PROGRESS_BOX or RESPOND_YES_TO_ALL);
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Folder.ParseName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folder-parsename) to retrieve a reference to a specific file in a ZIP archive "folder". Then pass that reference to [`Folder.CopyHere`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folder-copyhere) to extract it.

```pascal
const
  NO_PROGRESS_BOX = 4;
  RESPOND_YES_TO_ALL = 16;

procedure UnZip(ZipPath, FileName, TargetPath: string); 
var
  Shell: Variant;
  ZipFile: Variant;
  Item: Variant;
  TargetFolder: Variant;
begin
  Shell := CreateOleObject('Shell.Application');

  ZipFile := Shell.NameSpace(ZipPath);
  if VarIsClear(ZipFile) then
    RaiseException(Format('Cannot open ZIP file "%s" or does not exist', [ZipPath]));

  Item := ZipFile.ParseName(FileName);
  if VarIsClear(Item) then
    RaiseException(Format('Cannot find "%s" in "%s" ZIP file', [FileName, ZipPath]));

  TargetFolder := Shell.NameSpace(TargetPath);
  if VarIsClear(TargetFolder) then
    RaiseException(Format('Target path "%s" does not exist', [TargetPath]));

  TargetFolder.CopyHere(Item, NO_PROGRESS_BOX or RESPOND_YES_TO_ALL);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a way that works, not what I was expected but is functional.

```
UnZip(AppFolder+'\modulos\seimpresoras-2.2.zip', tmpFolder); 
FileCopy(tmpFolder+'\seimpresoras\resources\default.properties', AppFolder+'\printers.properties', False);
```